# The script does not work in IE. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html

There is a script that changes the page template depending on the user's monitor screen resolution. However, it does not work in IE. Advise how to fix it, please.

```
<body>
<table id="mt" align="center" >
<tr>
<td colspan=3 id=top>{{head}}</td></tr><tr><td id=t1>&nbsp;</td><td id=t3>&nbsp;</td><td id=t2>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr>
<td id=1eft valign=top>{{left}}</td>
<td id=content><h1>[*pagetitle*]</h1>[*content*]</td>
<td id=right>{{right}}</td></tr>
<tr><td id=ft colspan=3>{{foot}}</td></tr>
</table><script>if (window.outerWidth>1440) {a='1440px';} else {a='auto';}document.getElementById("mt").style.width = a;</script></body>
```

Comment: *"The script does not work in IE."* **How** does it not work? What happens on IE? Nothing? The templates get the wrong size? You see error messages in the script console? *(Hint)* Everything turns a lovely shade of fucshia? ;-)

Comment: __[IE8]__ `alert(window.outerWidth);` <-- returns undefined.

Comment: >>[IE8] alert(window.outerWidth); <-- returns undefined. How i can replace window.outerWidth for IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`outerWidth` is supported by IE, but since from the IE9.

[Replacement](http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/javascript/f699.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

Not all browsers have the window.outerWidth and window.outerHeight properties.  Geek Daily has a good post on [cross-browser window size detection](http://www.geekdaily.net/2007/07/04/javascript-cross-browser-window-size-and-centering/).  I'd suggest looking there.  As an example, here's what I get in each browser on a desktop with 1280x1024 resolution.

**Chrome**

```
window.outerWidth
1288
document.body.offsetWidth
1264
document.documentElement.offsetWidth
1280
```

**Firefox**

```
window.outerWidth
1288
document.body.offsetWidth
1238
document.documentElement.offsetWidth
1264
```

**IE7** Doctype Defined

```
window.outerWidth
undefined
document.body.offsetWidth
1260
document.documentElement.offsetWidth
1260
```

**IE7** No Doctype/Quirks Mode

```
window.outerWidth
undefined
document.body.offsetWidth
1260
document.documentElement.offsetWidth
1280
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few other problems

- All of your attribute values should be in quotes. for example. `id="value"`
- you have LEFT spelled 1(number 1)eft

Comment: Thanks, but this does not affect the problem