# JW player is not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, jwplayer

I am just checking JW Players in compatibility with all browser. 
    But, Not even a blank screen is coming in IE 8 browser, in other browsers it works well.

I have already read the link [JWPlayer Not Working for Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983801/jwplayer-not-working-for-internet-explorer-8) but couldn't get any help.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
if((window.outerWidth && window.outerWidth > 640) || (document.body.clientWidth && 
document.body.clientWidth > 640)){
alert('error'); 
 }
</script>
<div id="myElement">Loading the player ...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "myVideo.mp4",
         image: "myPoster.jpg",
           });

</script>
<ul>
    <li onclick='jwplayer().play()'>Start playback</li>
    <li onclick='alert(jwplayer().getVolume())'>Get audio volume</li>
    <li onclick='jwplayer().pause();'>pause</li>

</ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please check console for errors..

Comment: how to check console for error in IE

Comment: thanks ..... it solved ... :) its working problem was with lesser flash version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "myVideo.mp4",
     image: "myPoster.jpg"
       });
</script>
```

comma removed

Comment: thanks it solved ... it is working now .....can u tell me why did we remove comma

Comment: @hitesh U dont need to put comma after the last attribute. Its a syntax error in ie.

Comment: IE doesn't like trailing commas, it isn't proper JSON notation to do that.